# Markov chains in nature

Tags: markov-process

It is a well known result that any Markov Chain with a regular transition matrix admits a limiting distribution. Any arbitrary transition matrix can be converted into a regular transition matrix by addition of a small perturbation to potential zero entries, guaranteeing that it contains all positive entries. This is a sufficient condition of the transition matrix to be regular and it thus admits a limiting distribution. So it seems that by an infinitesimal perturbation of any transition matrix we can guarantee that the resulting Markov Chain admits a limiting distribution. Is this correct?

If so, do we know of systems in nature that evolve according to Markov Chains and do not admit a limiting distribution? By the logic that any system in nature inevitably suffers from small perturbations or noise this would lead me to the conclusion that Markov Chains that do not admit limiting distributions are not very physical.

Comment: In Nature, the difficulty is in keeping the Markov chain transition homogeneous. A common example is the Old Faithful geyser in Yellowstone National Park, Wyoming, where the delays between eruptions are more or less Markovian but vary with external factors.